# jQuery getJSON not populating HTML select properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an HTML `<select>`:

```
<div id="content">
    <input type="button" id="get-btn" onclick="getData();"/>
    <select id="attrib-type-sel"></select>
</div>
```

When the user clicks the following button, I want to use jQuery's `getJSON` method to hit my server, pull back data, and populate the `<select>` with options:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON(
        "some/url/on/my/server",
        function(data) {
        var optionsHTML = "";
        var len = data.length;
        for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            optionsHTML += '<option value="' + data[i] + '">'
                + data[i] + '</option>';
        }

        $('#attrib-type-sel').html(optionsHTML);
    });
});
```

When I run this code, in Firebug, I see that the AJAX call is successful and returns the following JSON:

```
[
    {
        "id":1,
        "name":"Snoopy",
        "tag":"SNOOPY",
        "allowsAll":false
    }
]
```

(Only returns 1 record).

However, when back in the UI, when this code fires it creates a `<select>` that has 1 options whose inner HTML reads `[object Object]`.

Can anyone spot what is going on here? It looks like my `getJSON` is OK, but the code to extract the JSON from the results and use it to populate my select is buggy. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

it's because that data[i] is an object. Try using `console.log(data[i])` to check out what it's looking like.

`data[i].id` and `data[i].name` are likely what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

you need `data[i].id` & `data[i].name` to construct your options.

```
for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        optionsHTML += '<option value="' + data[i].id + '">'
            + data[i].name + '</option>';
}
```